# Processing or dealing with emails with Failed Recipient

Tags: coldfusion, gmail-api

We have a Coldfusion server that sends out emails. From time to time, those emails will bounce or fail and those notices are returned to me in my gmail account. Is there a way I can parse those emails and remove the invalid emails from our database maybe with a gmail api? The emails are sent via a newsletter subscription so there is an unsubscribe option. In the bounced message, it would be possible to obtain the userid (thinking cfhttp here) and then I could parse that out to get the userID and then unsubscribe/delete that user so that the next time the newsletter is sent, we don't get the bounced notices again.

Is the Google API the right line of thinking here? (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete)

Comment: This is on an older CF9 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I did this but I just had `<cfpop>` login to the email account in question, search for emails with a specific subject, gather up the data I wanted from there, like the email address it bounced from, and update the database using an IN clause based on a list of bounced email addresses.

Just make sure to delete the messages you've scanned afterwards.

However, in CF10+, you can use the secure attribute instead of invoking java for the secure connection.

```
<cfpop
   server="pop.gmail.com"
   action="getHeaderOnly"
   name="popMessages" port="995" maxrows="10"
   username="user@gmail.com"
   password="password"
   secure="yes|no">
```

A quick google for how to access gmail with cfpop returned this, useful for connecting with older CFs.

```
<!---
 See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html
 Warning: Changing system properties is potentially dangerous and should be 
 done with discretion.
--->
<cfset javaSystem = createObject("java", "java.lang.System") />
<cfset javaSystemProps = javaSystem.getProperties() />
<cfset javaSystemProps.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory") />

<cfpop
   server="pop.gmail.com"
   action="getHeaderOnly"
   name="popMessages" port="995" maxrows="10"
   username="user@gmail.com"
   password="password">
```

Comment: are you also on easycfm? I haven't "talked" with you in ages! I hope you are doing well and thank you for the help.

Comment: @dlackey I think you're thinking of someone else. Sorry.

Comment: cfqueryparam - You must have hit some old entries. IIRC, CF8+ support ssl and tls via attributes. Also be very careful changing system properties, as you are changing them across the board for the entire jvm ...

Comment: Yeah I'll remove the java bit, I literally just googled cfpop gmail and came up with that for a code sample, but I'll update it, I don't want to encourage bad form.

Comment: FYI: Added the warning from the javadocs, in case someone does not read the comments. Granted, the java hack should not be needed unless using a *really* old version ie MX7 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly write code (using CFPOP or cfImap) to check your email inbox for bounces. It would be better if the FROM address was dedicated to the newsletter rather than being your personal inbox - since those emails will be intermingled with your personal email.

There is an App by Brian Ghidinelli on Ria Forge called [Email Bounce Detector](http://bouncedetector.riaforge.org/) that can help you examine each message to determine if it is a bounce.

One thing to note, some bounces should *not* be flagged for removal. A mailbox full message for example, or a temporary deferrment (grey listing). So your logic needs to track not just "did it bounce" but why and how many times. Typically, there's a threshold - 3 times consectutive over a week or something - that makes sense given your list.

Comment: The gmail isn't my personal account so no issues there but you do make some good points there. Thanks for the feedback.